# Question on: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: ssl, certificate

Someone posted the code snippet here as a temporary workaround for accepting certificates. I would've followed up there but I don't have enough points to comment yet, so this has to be a new question.

As a total SSL neophyte, can anyone tell me where this snippet of code would go in a c# rest service? Does it go in startup.cs, program.cs, in the endpoint of the called service, or the method of the client that calls the service...

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: Clearly I don't know how to add code to a post yet, sorry. The snippet in question is at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Oh I should also mention I'm using C# in a .Net Core 5.0 framework and deploying to a Linux (Ubuntu) Docker container.